# What kind of spider is this? (Central Texas)

Tags: species-identification

This is in Austin, TX, USA. Photos taken at night on a phone with a flash, so colors may not be entirely accurate.

[image: unidentified spider]

[image: unidentified spider]

I found this spider hiding inside my motorcycle cover, which I'd thrown in a pile on my front porch for a few days.

It wasn't aggressive nor skittish, although it did scuttle away at a relatively slow pace as soon as I tried to move it using a large envelope. I would estimate its diameter (legs included) at about 1-1/2 to 2 inches (38mm - 51mm).

I was very cautious around it since I thought it might be a brown recluse, but I know there are a number of Central Texas spiders that bear a resemblance. I couldn't make out the "violin" on its back but I also didn't get close enough to make sure.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a Southern House Spider? It appears very similar to the brown recluse although without the violin you were unable to find on the thorax.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_house_spider

[image]

Photo from [Spider ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TVp6.png)

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes - I think you're likely correct! (I'll leave this open for contributions but then accept your answer if there's not a better guess soon.) The picture in the Wikipedia article doesn't strongly resemble my photo; but, that species has strong sexual dimorphism. Of the other photos I googled, I found a few that look spot-on. Maybe the Wikipedia photo shows a male and this was a female, or vice-versa. This photo, for example, looks like the exact same spider (note eye position, abdomen size & texture, leg gradation, etc.): https://www.pinterest.com/pin/391109548883253068/

Comment: @Bungle & JEJS: I can't speak for the downvoter, but answers are more likely to get a positive response if they explain why an identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion, which is inappropriate for this site. ——— You may also wish to consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site.

Comment: I agree with K. hibernalis. The answer should probably be modified from "Maybe a..." to "This is a..."